# Android location to string issue

Tags: java, android, android-location

Here is the code I use the put locations to strings:

```
public static String locationStringFromLocation(final Location location) {
    return String.format("%.3f %.3f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
}
```

And from some other devices, from time to time I get:
`-7.2900002123788E-4 7.270000060088933E-4` as location string and not `-7.290 7.270` for example.

- Does someone has clue on this?
- How to improve my code?

**Edit**

Updated code.
Will this fix the issue?

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
if (location != null) {
    final String latitude = decimalFormat.format(Float.valueOf(Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES)));
    final String longitude = decimalFormat.format(Float.valueOf(Location.convert(location.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES)));
    return latitude + " " + longitude;
}
return decimalFormat.format(0.0F) + " " + decimalFormat.format(0.0F);
```

Comment: Your code looks ok for me. On what Android versions do you test?

Comment: @Fildor I target API-17, building for API-7+. The weird case appeared on a API-10.

Comment: API-10 is always buggy... SavedState, graphics, now formatting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `public static String convert (double coordinate, int outputType)` from Location Class. The outputType can be one of `FORMAT_DEGREES`, `FORMAT_MINUTES`, or `FORMAT_SECONDS`.

```
public static String locationStringFromLocation(final Location location) {
    return Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES) + " " + Location.convert(location.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
}
```

Comment: Is this just another way of doing it or is it a fix you know?

Comment: This is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/location/Location.java#Location.convert%28double%2Cint%29 This is how Android does it. A little more effort than just String.format ;)

Answer (score 0):

one line, one method, convinient workaround:

```
String.substring(beginIndex,finalIndex)
```

so in your case:

```
latInDecimal = lat.substring(0,5)
lngInDecimal = lng.substring(0,5)
```